# Symfony error when i try to generate my fixtures with nelmio/alice

Tags: yaml, symfony, fixtures, nelmio-alice

I tried to generate my fixtures and i got this error :

```
 Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class FinanceBundle\Entity\Conversion could not be converted to string
```

Here my related entities :

ConversionLink entity

```
          ...
/** 
        *
        * @var Conversion
        *
        * @ORM\Column(name="""conversionID""", type="bigint")
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FinanceBundle\Entity\Conversion")
        * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="""conversionID""", referencedColumnName="""ID""")
        */
       private $conversion;
... //getter setters and so on
```

Conversion entity contain nothing about this relation. Only others independant fields.

Here my conversion path fixtures

```
FinanceBundle\Entity\ConversionLink:
   conversionLink{1..5}:
       # some fields ...
       conversion: '@conversion*'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your fixture file should look like this:

```
FinanceBundle\Entity\ConversionLink:
   conversionLink{1..5}:
       # some fields ...
       conversion: '@conversion<current()>'
```

Comment: I've tried, but it's the same. "*" just pickup one entity randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FinanceBundle\Entity\ConversionLink:
   conversionLink{1..5}:
       # some fields ...
       conversion: '@conversion$current'
```